# Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 Developer - Unable to create data source using admin console

Tags: jdbc, weblogic12c

I have been trying to create a DataSource on my development machine using Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 developer install using the admin console and I am getting an exception that I have not encountered before. I have verified that all of the connection information is correct and I can connect to the Oracle Database (v12.1.2) using SQL Developer and an IDE connection but the Weblogic server is not cooperating.
This is the exception that I am getting:

[image: DS Creation Exception]

I have also tried creating a DataSource when the EAR file is deployed using descriptors and the DS is created and deployed but the connection pool for the DS cannot be created and the only exception that I am seeing is this:

> Connection test failed with the following exception: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'StipDS'. The DBMS driver exception was: null

Anyone have any ideas? 
Oracle has not been much help at all so far.

Comment: I am currently working with the Oracle JDBC team on the problem. It is looking like there is a bug in jdbc drivers that ship with this version of Weblogic server.

Comment: The problem was being caused by a bug in the ojdbc8.jar that shipped with the developers version of Weblogic 12.2.1.3. I replaced the ojdbc8.jar with ojdbc7.jar and everything worked as it should have. This problem did appear with the full version of Weblogic 12.2.1.3 on the stand alone server installations.

Answer (score 1):

check your jdbc connection url, i guess something is missing there. make sure the jdbc driver is present inside lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and able to resolve by replacing the ojdbc6.jar with ojdbc6-2.0.jar from "C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib"

Downloaded the jar file from https://jar-download.com/?search_box=ojdbc6++jar

Error log:

```
Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: null
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:283)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1310)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1227)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:250)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.doStart(ConnectionPool.java:1329)
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest reverting any network changes that might have taken place.
example DNS change in the resolve.conf file